# How to replace all the values in JSON structure using javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, data-structures

If I have JSON structure like this, I want to parse this JSON replace all values with '{param.keyName}', if the key value is array of objects than need to generate its value like {param.headKey[index]keyName}

```
{
          "resources": [
            {
              "name": "prod",
              "type": "local",
              "properties": {
                "zone": "asia",
                "disks": [
                  {
                    "sizeGb": 3,
                    "diskType": "boot",
                    "name": "backup"
                  },
                  {
                    "sizeGb": 4,
                    "diskType": "ssd",
                    "name": "cache"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
```

The output of the function should be JSON like this where all the values should be replaced with the mapping. If there is any array of objects than it should prefixed by array index like {param.disks0_name}, where disks is an array of objects.

```
{
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "prod",
      "type": "local",
      "properties": {
        "zone": "{param.zone}",
        "disks": [
          {
            "sizeGb": '{param.disks0_sizeGb}',
            "diskType": '{param.disks0_diskType}',
            "name": "{param.disks0_name}"
          },
          {
            "sizeGb": '{param.disks1_zone}',
            "diskType": '{param.disks1_diskType}',
            "name": "{param.disks1_name}"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could look for the arrays/objects and iterate them for getting the path for the last property.

Format as desired (which is unclear for nested arrays).

```js
function formatPath(path) {
    return `{${path.join('.')}}`;
}

function getPath(object, path = []) {
    return Object.assign(
        Array.isArray(object) ? [] : {},
        ...Object.entries(object).map(([k, v]) => ({
            [k]: v && typeof v === 'object'
                ? getPath(v, path.concat(k))
                : formatPath(path.concat(k))
        }))
    );
}

var data = { resources: [{ name: "prod", type: "local", properties: { zone: "asia", disks: [{ sizeGb: 3, diskType: "boot", name: "backup" }, { sizeGb: 4, diskType: "ssd", name: "cache" }] } }] };

data = { resources: data.resources.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, { properties: getPath(o.properties, ['param']) })) };

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
function formatPath(path) {
    return '{' + path.join('.') + '}';
}

function getPath(object, path) {
    path = path || [];
    return Object.keys(object).reduce(
        function (r, k) {
            r[k] = object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object'
                ? getPath(object[k], path.concat(k))
                : formatPath(path.concat(k));
            return r;
        }, 
        Array.isArray(object) ? [] : {}
    );
}

var data = { resources: [{ name: "prod", type: "local", properties: { zone: "asia", disks: [{ sizeGb: 3, diskType: "boot", name: "backup" }, { sizeGb: 4, diskType: "ssd", name: "cache" }] } }] };

data = { resources: data.resources.map(function (o) { 
    return Object.keys(o).reduce(function (r, k) {
        r[k] = k === 'properties'
            ? getPath(o.properties, ['param'])
            : o[k];
        return r;
    }, {});
 }) };

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks so much. @nina scholz, I need the code in ES5.